# Deserializar un JSON que puede ser solo un objeto a una Lista<T>

Tags: c#, json, serialización

Tengo un problema que no sé solucionar.

Tengo un objeto `Movimientos`, y tras una llamada a un ApiRest, obtengo una lista de ellos, los cuales deserializo de la siguiente forma.

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimientos>>(contenido);
```

Hasta aquí perfecto, el problema es cuando mi llamada a la Api devuelve **solamente** un `Movimiento`, que la misma línea de la deserialización salta:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Movimientos]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object."}

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo para que funcione tanto con un json que contenga una lista como para un único elemento?

Edito con más datos simplificados:
Un json de ejemplo que devuelve el api es

```
string contenido = "{ \"NumeroOrden\":null,\"Operacion\":null}";
```

Y la clase Movimientos

```
public class Movimientos
{
  public string NumeroOrden { get; set; }
  public string Operacion { get; set; }
}
```

Edito: **El Json** que obtengo debe ser inmutable.
Lo que devuelve la api no es mío, no depende de mí y por tanto **no puede ser modificado**.

Comment: Lo he añadido, pero no creo que sea necesario

Comment: Como retornas el objeto `Movimientos` ??? lo que pasa es que estas tratando de convertir una lista entonces lo que tienes que hacer es cuando retornes el objeto `Movimientos` debes devolver una lista como sea así sea que solo venga uno o vengas mil, si no siempre te va a sacar error. en tu api al retornar el objeto lo puedes enviar con un `.toList()`

Comment: Lo que devuelve la api no es mío, no depende de mí y por tanto no puede ser modificado. Añado este comentario a la pregunta.

Comment: @Fran, no se si sea la mejor forma pero valida con el error en un try cacht si el error se presenta cambias la forma en la que realizas la serializacion  quitando el list, si no ps utilizas el normal que tiene list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que no puedes modificar el API REST (según indicas en los comentarios), debes entonces **controlar el código**, para comprobar si lo que te devuelve el Web API es un Array o un Objeto simple.

Puedes hacerlo de **muchas formas**, te indico dos:

**1** - **Mediante excepciones** (Try/Catch)

```
        List<Movimientos> result;
        var contenido = "{ \"NumeroOrden\":null,\"Operacion\":null}";

        try
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimientos>>(contenido);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Si lanza la excepción es que es un solo elemento.
            var singleResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movimientos>(contenido);
            result = new List<Movimientos>();
            result.Add(singleResult);
        }
```

**2** - **Comprobando si es Array** (Comienza por '[' y finaliza por ']')

```
        List<Movimientos> result;
        var contenido = "[{ \"NumeroOrden\":null,\"Operacion\":null}]";

        if (contenido.StartsWith("[") && contenido.EndsWith("]"))
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimientos>>(contenido);
        }
        else
        {
            var singleResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movimientos>(contenido);
            result = new List<Movimientos>();
            result.Add(singleResult);
        }
```

Por supuesto, estas son dos formas **orientativas** de hacerlo (mejorables), ahora todo depende de tu aplicación y tu **nivel de programación**.

---

**UPDATE:**

Según tu comentario:

> *Por lo que tengo entendido, no es recomendable usar excepciones como condiciones, por lo que he optado por la segunda opción y por el
>   momento funciona bien.*

Efectivamente, no es recomendable utilizar **Excepciones genéricas** para flujos condicionales de control. Pero existen casos (como el tuyo) en los que una **mala programación** que no se puede subsanar (como el Web API que consumes) requiere de métodos **poco ortodoxos** para solucionar el problema. A veces, (y no siempre) ***el fin justifica los medios***.

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, no es recomendable usar excepciones como condiciones, por lo que he optado por la segunda opción y por el momento funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dije en mi comentario puedes realizar lo siguiente:

Agregar el `try catch` dentro del `try` ejecutas tu código el cual valida si vienes varios elementos en el Objeto no pasa nada retorna normal, pero si viene solo un elemento te va  generar un error con esto validas dentro del `catch` vas a poner el código con el cual solo **deserializas** un objeto.

```
  var contenido = "{\"NumeroOrden\":null,\"Operacion\":null}";

   try
   {
      result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimientos>>(contenido);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movimientos>(contenido);
   }
```